# Is it possible to lazy load Jquery (not a plugin)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got several JavaScript files that load along with many of my pages, costing valuable tens of kilobytes of data download. One of these is a version of `jquery.min.js` which although minified, is still 25kb or so.

My issue is that a huge chunk of mobile phones don't support JavaScript so the downloading of this and other JS files is a waste of data. Is there anyway to lazy load the JQuery file by adding a `<script>` tag in the page that calls the JS file and would obviously only execute if a browser supports JavaScript, which would only then make sense to download it?

Comment: If a browser doesn't support JavaScript, I don't think it would download the script, Firefox doesn't.

Comment: I've just tested this with Firefox and Firebug. Looks like you're right (I didn't know this, thanks). A definitive answer for mobile browsers would be comforting.

Comment: If you have access to your server's access log, you can just watch it while you make a request.

Comment: Just checked my logs. Looks like they don't even load, which makes this question redundant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To load script files only under certain conditions, I have used something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write('<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.min.js"></scr'+'ipt>');
</script>
```

Note: this only works inline, after the document is done loading, document.write() will have undesired effects.

Note 2: It is important to break `'</script>'`  like `'</scr'+'ipt>'` so as to not confuse the browser's parser into thinking your true script block is ended.  I do the opening script tag the same way for good measure.

Comment: Nice snippet :) Would be good to explain why you are using 'Scr' + 'ipt' instead of 'Script' (I know why, I just think it should be explained in your post)

Answer (score 0):

```
function loadScript(filename) {
  var t = document.createElement('script'),
      s = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

  t.type = 'text/javascript'; 
  t.async = true;
  t.src = filename;
  s.parentNode.appendChild(t);
}

// If and when jQuery is needed, you'd load it with:
loadScript('http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js');
```

Comment: This will work, but only if there is already a script tag in the document. If there are no other scripts being included, this will fail.